# registration form encryption using vb.net and mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, password-encryption

I have a registration form and I want to encrypt the password using whatever encryption is available, I'm using vb.net 2008 and MySQL as database, I searched through online and found some encrypting code but I have no idea how to connect it to my registration form. here is my registration code and the encryption code i found online (at the top part)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Imports System.Security

Imports System.Security.Cryptography


Public Class user

Public Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim encrypted As String = ""
    Try
        Dim hash(31) As Byte
        Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
        AES.Key = hash
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return encrypted

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function

Private Sub BCreateAcount_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BCreateAcount.Click
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection

    conn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost;username= root;password= a;database= database"

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch mali As MySqlException
        MsgBox("connot establish connection")
    End Try
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader


    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = "insert into user values('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + txtNewPassword.Text + "')"
    Call calldaw()


    If txtUserName.Text = "" Or txtNewPassword.Text = "" Or txtConfirmPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter username and password", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Inventory System")
    ElseIf txtConfirmPassword.Text = txtNewPassword.Text Then

        MsgBox("Account Created", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Inventory System")
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        txtUserName.Text = ""
        txtNewPassword.Text = ""
        txtConfirmPassword.Text = ""

    Else
        MsgBox("Password did not match", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Inventory System")
        txtConfirmPassword.Text = ""
        txtNewPassword.Text = ""
        txtUserName.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub calldaw()
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection

    conn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost;username= root;password= a;database= database"

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch mali As MySqlException
        MsgBox("connot establish connection")
    End Try

    Dim myData As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim reason As String = " Create Account "
    Dim tao As String = "admin"

    myData = New MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim sqlsql = "insert into daily_log values('" + tao + "','" + Date1.Text + "','" + reason + "','" + Time1.Text + "')"
    Dim ssql = "Select * from user"

    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = sqlsql

    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

End Sub

Private Sub BBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BBack.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub user_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Date1.Text = Date.Today.Date
    Dim Date2 As Date = Date1.Text
    Date1.Text = Format(Date2, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Time1.Text = TimeOfDay
End Sub

End Class
```

any help will do, thanks.

Comment: You have the encryption method with two parameters. First try to understand it and pass the password as a parameter to that method or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the AES_Encrypt function before executing the INSERT statement in order to pass the encrypted password to database.

```
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader


myCommand.Connection = conn
myCommand.CommandText = "insert into user values('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + AES_Encrypt(txtNewPassword.Text,txtNewPassword.Text) + "')"
Call calldaw()
```

Comment: thank you so much, never thought it was this short of a answer, :)

Comment: does this also work on decryption,? I have thesame code but only changed the line to "AES_Decrypt"  should i put this in this code: Dim sqlQuery = "Select * from user where username = ' " + textbox1.text + "' and password = ' " + textbox2.text " ' "

Comment: Yes, it should be. You can use the same function since you are just passing the same value to query the record on DB. You can double check if every same words have the same encrypted value.

Comment: Sorry, press the Enter key. You can simply do it like this.

Comment: AGAIN..!!! Sorry... lols

  im sqlQuery = "Select * from user where username = ' " + textbox1.text + "' and password = ' " + AES_Encrypt(textbox2.text,textbox2.text) " '

Comment: haha, I also struggled with the Enter key in here, anyway, great help, thank you :)

Comment: hahaha... welcome. I would also suggest not to duplicate the same function by AES_Decrypt. Using the same function should do the trick and reserved AES_Descrypt for future use when you need to display back the original value. :)